# Laravel Sail Stopped Working with "bad variable name"

Tags: laravel-9

Suddenly all `sail` commands stopped working with an error

```
vendor/bin/sail: 26: export: PROJECTS/Laravel9/myproj/vendor/bin: bad variable name
```

Line 26 on `vendor/bin/sail` has:

```
export COMPOSER_RUNTIME_BIN_DIR=$(cd "${self%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; pwd)
```

What is the reason and how can I recover? Thanks!

I am using

```
Windows 10
WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04)
Docker Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my folder name has the **space** `IT PROJECTS`. Somehow the `IT`  part was not included in the export.

Renaming my folder to `PROJECTS` solved the problem